# copy column from excel to notepad++, then copy back to excel

Tags: excel, notepad++

I copy column A from excel to notepad++, then do some editing,
then copy from notepad++ back to excel

however, when it is pasted back to excel, the data expands into column B and C.

So I think using Microsoft Word as a workaround,  I copy from notepad++ to Word , then copy from word to excel, the data successfully stays within only column A in Excel.

I have many files, it would be the best to only copy between notepad++ and excel.

so how to keep data in column A only when copy from notepad++ to excel?

thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Add sample data from Notepad++ by editing your question. What do you mean by **do some editing**?

Comment: Perhaps you are adding some TABs when editing with notepad++?

Comment: I only did find and replaced some text in notepad++ , which excel failed to do. I tested that even without doing any editing or text replacing, copy and paste back to excel still expands to column B and C

Answer (score 0):

1. Export your text from Excel as [CSV file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values).
2. Do your changes in exported CSV file. While editing, keep the [CSV syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Basic_rules).
3. Import your text from CSV back to the Excel.

I strongly recommend to explicitly select encoding **UTF-8** when exporting and importing the CSV. If you check closer, that option is available in both export and import. Otherwise there is a risk of damaging of special characters (national characters, symbols etc) potentially contained in the file.